# Complete a json string from incomplete HTTP JSON response

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, api, http

Sometimes I will download data from a json api, and it cuts off mid-way, usually due to network timeout or some other issues. However, in such scenarios I would like to be able to read the available data. Here is an example:

```
{
    "response": 200,
    "message": None,
    "params": []
    "body": {
        "timestamp": 1546033192,
        "_d": [
                {"id": "FMfcgxwBTsWRDsWDqgqRtZlLMdpCpTDz"},
                {"id": "FMfcgxwBTkFSKqRrcKzMFvLCjDSSbrJH"},
                {"id": "Fmfgo9
```

I would like to be able to "complete the string" so that I'm able to parse the incomplete response as json. For example:

```
s = '''
{
    "response": 200,
    "message": null,
    "params": [],
    "body": {
        "timestamp": 1546033192,
        "_d": [
                {"id": "FMfcgxwBTsWRDsWDqgqRtZlLMdpCpTDz"},
                {"id": "FMfcgxwBTkFSKqRrcKzMFvLCjDSSbrJH"}
              ]
    }
}'''
json.loads(s)
{'response': 200, 'message': None, 'params': [], 'body': {'timestamp': 1546033192, '_d': [{'id': 'FMfcgxwBTsWRDsWDqgqRtZlLMdpCpTDz'}, {'id': 'FMfcgxwBTkFSKqRrcKzMFvLCjDSSbrJH'}]}}
```

How would I be able to do the above with an arbitrarily constructed json object such as the above?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't, it could be any arbitrary structure. Guessing the end of the structure is probably not helpful.

Comment: @roganjosh could we count the number of "unfinished" `}`s and `]`s and try and complete it by adding that in (and potentially any unfinished quotation marks?

Comment: You would need to write your own JSON parser from scratch. In this case, at the point the data cuts off you should be able to walk back up your parse tree and close any "open" arrays, dictionaries, etc.

Comment: How are you even getting the partial response? If there's a network error, I'd expect the library to throw an exception and not return anything.

Comment: @larsks do you see any striking issues with the basic parser I've written below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way I did it, building a stack of `}` and `]` characters to try and 'finish off'. It's a bit verbose and can be cleaned up, but it works on a few string inputs I've tried:

```
s='''{
"response": 200,
"message": null,
"params": [],
"body": {
    "timestamp": 1546033192,
    "_d": [
            {"id": "FMfcgxwBTsWRDsWDqgqRtZlLMdpCpTDz"},
            {"id": "FMfcgxwBTkFSKqRrcKzMFvLCjDSSbrJH"},
            {"id": "Fmfgo9'''

>>> f.complete_json_structure(s)
{'response': 200, 'message': None, 'params': [], 'body': {'timestamp': 1546033192, '_d': [{'id': 'FMfcgxwBTsWRDsWDqgqRtZlLMdpCpTDz'}, {'id': 'FMfcgxwBTkFSKqRrcKzMFvLCjDSSbrJH'}]}}
```

Here is the code:

```
# Build the 'unfinished character' stack
unfinished = []
for char in file_data:
    if char in ['{', '[']:
        unfinished.append(char)
    elif char in ['}', ']']:
        inverse_char = '{' if char == '}' else '['
        # Remove the last one
        unfinished.reverse()
        unfinished.remove(inverse_char)
        unfinished.reverse()

# Build the 'closing occurrence string' 
unfinished.reverse()
unfinished = ['}' if (char == '{') else ']' for char in unfinished]
unfinished_str = ''.join(unfinished)

# Do a while loop to try and parse the json
data = None
while True:

    if not json_string:
        raise FileParserError("Could not parse the JSON file or infer its format.")

    if json_string[-1] in ('}', ']'):

        try:
            data = json.loads(json_string + unfinished_str)
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
            # do it a second time as a sort of hack to fix the "trailing comma issue" (or could do a remove last comma, but that gets tricky)
            try:
                data = json.loads(json_string + unfinished_str[1:])
            except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
                pass

        if data is not None:
            break

    if json_string[-1] == unfinished_str[0]:
        unfinished_str = unfinished_str[1:]

    json_string = json_string[:-1].strip().rstrip(',')

return data
```

Comment: @user10503628 you're referencing the json_string variable before assignment. What is it supposed to be?

Comment: json_string is referenced before assignmnet. Where do you declare it?

Answer (score 1):

The idea of writing a parser for this task is really intellectually interesting, but I would strongly caution you from following this approach.

The fundamental issue is that you are entering into the realm of undefined behavior when a network request fails. You have absolutely no guarantees what your resulting output would be, so you probably shouldn't try to finagle one.

The two possibilities are either that your input is incomplete but partially comprehensible, or it is completely incomprehensible. The added complexity combined with the undefined nature of a failed network request means you probably shouldn't try and define it anyway.

Take, for example, how the [TCP/IP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_protocol_suite) deals with a similar issue. With networks, there is often [packet loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_loss), meaning some part of the data fails to transmit completely. To quote Wikipedia, TCP "detects packet loss and performs retransmissions to ensure reliable messaging".

I strongly suggest a similar approach. Either re-fetch the data or simple take the error as gospel and do something with the error state.

Comment: I agree with that. I'm just using the "failed http request" as an example -- we use exponential backoff and about 1000 lines of code to handle some of retrying, etc. The above question is more about "how to arbitrarily parse incomplete json", and I'm just using an incomplete http response as an example (it could also be loading a file in chunks, etc.)

Comment: Roger that. It's a really interesting question, then!

Answer (score 0):

```
import re

add_bracket_pattern = r'Expecting \',\' delimiter: .* \(char (?P<pos>\d+)\)'

strip_string_pattern = r'Unterminated string starting at: line (\d+) column (\d+) \(char (?P<pos>\d+)\)'

strip_tail_pattern = r'(Expecting (property name enclosed in double quotes|value|\':\' delimiter):|Invalid (control character|.*escape)).*\(char (?P<pos>\d+)\)'

def parse_incomplete(json_str):
    digit_trunk = True
    while True:
        try:
            if not json_str:
                return None
            return json.loads(json_str)
        except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
            match = re.search(add_bracket_pattern, e.args[0])
            if match:
                pos = int(match.group('pos'))
                if pos == len(json_str):
                    if json_str[pos - 1].isdigit() and digit_trunk:
                        json_str = json_str[0:-1]
                    else:
                        json_str = json_str + ']'
                else:
                    json_str = json_str[:pos] + '}'
                continue
            else:
                digit_trunk = False

            match = re.search(strip_string_pattern, e.args[0])
            if match:
                start_pos = int(match.group('pos'))
                json_str = json_str[0:start_pos]
                continue

            if re.search(strip_tail_pattern, e.args[0]):
                json_str = json_str[0:-1]
                continue
            raise e
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).