# What is the best way to validate a large json file before reading it into a pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, json, pyspark

I have to read a large (roughly 1500 lines) json file into a pyspark data frame, and take into account incomplete json objects and unexpected line endings. The file has one json object per line, and looks like this:

```
{"place":{"place_name":"Chicago","place_id": 23654},"category":"city","population":8000000}...}
{"place":{"place_name":"New York","place_id": 23754},"category":"city","population":10000000}...}
```

I found an example of how to fix broken json objects, but that would require me to iterate over the file line by line (accepted answer here: [Complete a json string from incomplete HTTP JSON response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53964597/complete-a-json-string-from-incomplete-http-json-response)). Is it a good strategy to do this and to rewrite any broken lines in the file before reading it into the pyspark dataframe?

Also, would a simple regex replace operation be enough to remove the unexpected line endings in the middle of the objects?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's not the line endings that cause the problem.  White space is ignored in JSON.  The issue is that you have a list, but it's not notated as a list.  You would need to add `"["` at the beginning, `"]"` at the end, and a comma at the end of every line except the last.  The format you have is something called  "jsonl" or "jsonlines".  There is a pypi package to read these.

Comment: @Tim Roberts so you mean I would need to add the [] characters to the beginning and the end and then use jsonlines? Or just to use jsonlines? Also, would using jsonlines be enough to validate the objects or would I need additional logic?

Comment: spark can read JSONL properly with `spark.read.json`. Also, Spark can isolate the broken record and keep it into a separate column (`_corrupt_record`) which you can apply your fixing logic on this column.  
Though, I don't see any issues in above JSONL (besides `...}` but I assumed this is a truncation for the sake of the question). Do you have trouble reading it?

Comment: One or the other.  Adding brackets and commas, would turn this into JSON, but what you have should work with jsonlines.

Comment: @Emma Thanks for the tip. I tried doing that but I get the following error when accessing the _corrupt_record column: pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: Since Spark 2.3, the queries from raw JSON/CSV files are disallowed when the
referenced columns only include the internal corrupt record column
(named _corrupt_record by default). Do you know of any workaround?

Comment: Yes, you cannot access ONLY the column like `select('_corrupt_record')`.  You can do this `df.show()` or `df.select('valid_col', '_corrupt_record').show()`

Here is a process you can try. First, to identify the corrupted line, `df.filter(F.col('_corrupt_record').isNotNull()).show()`. Also, check how much records do you have (corrupt/all records%)?

And see if the pattern of corruptions is same across all records? If so, then it could be something like `withColumn('fixed', F.concat(F.col('_corrupt_record', ...)))` to apply for all records.  If it varies, you need more complex logic.